# How can I see a piechart breakdown of contributions by financial type this year?

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, civisualize

The "Donor Report (Summary)" produces pie charts, however these seem to be only by date, even if I choose group by Financial Type. Also, it complains *"Do not use filter on Date if group by Receive Date is not used"* if I turn off date grouping. But I need a chart that shows the data by financial type not date, but within a given range (e.g. this year).

The "Donor Report (Detail)" allows me to summarise the data in a text format - the data I want is in the headings; I can't find a way to have only this displayed, or in a pie chart.

Would I need to write a custom report for this functionality, or is there something I'm missing?

I'm on 4.4 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [civisualize](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisualize-missing-data-visualization-extension)? the contribution dataviz got you covered

Comment: No, sounds exciting I'll check it out. I think the link is actually https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisualize-missing-data-visualization-extension

Comment: fixed the url, thanks and let me know what you think about it

Comment: @artfulrobot did you check civisualize? did it work as you wanted?

Comment: I love it! I'm pretty excited about this. I've [worked with d3 before](http://weownit.org.uk/privatisation-people-vs-politicians) (though not dc) and think it's fab, and I love the freedom to write some SQL! When I've figured it out I'll post back what I did.